# reshaping an arbitrary collection numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, scientific-computing

I have a relatively small number *k* of length *N* numpy arrays, where *k* is of order 10, and *N* is very large, of order 10^7. I am trying to create a single, two-dimensional *N* x *k* array that bundles this data in a specific way.

For definiteness, here is a specific example of what I am trying to do.

```
x = np.array([0,0,0,0])
y = np.array([1,1,1,1])
z = np.array([2,2,2,2])
```

The array I want at the end is:

```
p = np.array([[0,1,2], [0,1,2], [0,1,2], [0,1,2]])
```

Speed is a critical issue, so for-looping is unacceptably slow. I have not been able to figure out how to use np.reshape or np.concatenate to do this, but I know there must be some simple, single line of numpy syntax for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few methods you could try:

- using [`vstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html#numpy.vstack) and transpose:

  ```
  p = numpy.vstack((x, y, z)).T
  ```
- using [`concatenate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html#numpy.concatenate) and [`reshape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy.reshape)

  ```
  p = numpy.concatenate((x, y, z)).reshape((3, len(x))).T
  ```
- allocating a new array and using `put`

  ```
  p = numpy.empty((len(x), 3))
  for i, a in enumerate((x, y, z)):
      p[:,i] = a
  ```

Along with timing results computed in iPython, for `len(x) == len(y) == len(z) == 1e7`:

```
In [57]: %timeit p = numpy.vstack((x, y, z)).T
10 loops, best of 3: 117 ms per loop

In [58]: %timeit p = numpy.concatenate((x, y, z)).reshape((3, len(x))).T
10 loops, best of 3: 120 ms per loop

In [60]: %timeit p = numpy.column_stack((x, y, z))
10 loops, best of 3: 159 ms per loop

In [66]: %%timeit
   ....: p = numpy.empty((len(x), 3), order='C')
   ....: for i, a in enumerate((x, y, z)):
   ....:   p[:,i] = a
   ....: 
10 loops, best of 3: 147 ms per loop

In [67]: %%timeit
   ....: p = numpy.empty((len(x), 3), order='F')
   ....: for i, a in enumerate((x, y, z)):
   ....:   p[:,i] = a
   ....: 
10 loops, best of 3: 119 ms per loop
```

I've also included the method from [ajcr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29879420/56541), and tried both row-major and column-major ordering in the last one. There seem to be roughly two sets of methods in terms of timing, the 120ms-like methods and the 150ms-like methods, and it's probably noteworthy that row-major order (`'C'`) is one of the latter set whereas column-major order (`'F'`) is one of the former set.

I suspect these values are not reliable enough to distinguish between the methods. I'd encourage you to do your own tests and see which is fastest.

Comment: On my machine, `numpy.vstack((x, y, z)).T` was faster than `numpy.column_stack((x, y, z))` marginally for `len(x)==100000` .+1 for the benchmarks! And, I think `column_stack` internally uses `vstack`

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`column_stack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html):

```
>>> np.column_stack([x, y, z])
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2]])
```

[Internally](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.9.1/numpy/lib/shape_base.py#L278) this makes the three arrays 2D (without making copies if possible), transposes them, and then concatenates thm. The concatenate function is an internal C function so it is likely to be efficient speed-wise.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `np.concatenate`

```
In [117]: np.concatenate(([x], [y], [z]), axis=0).T
Out[117]:
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2]])
```

Also, You could append the arrays iteratively and then transpose.

Note: This does 3 loops.

```
In [113]: arr = np.empty((0,4), int)

In [114]: for el in [x, y, z]:
   .....:     arr = np.append(arr, [el], axis=0)
   .....:

In [115]: arr
Out[115]:
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2]])

In [116]: arr.T
Out[116]:
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2]])
```

Comment: Aha! Yes, it looks like the .T transpose syntax is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks to everyone for the helpful answers. As I suspected, there are one-liners in numpy for exactly this purpose. Transpose, vstack, and column_stack are all vast speed improvements on what I was doing.

There are four proposed solutions, all of which return the correct arrays:

- **concatenate + transpose** (David Z)
- **vstack** (David Z)
- **pre-allocate + slice-wise assignment** (David Z)
- **column_stack** (ajcr)

The upshot take-away of the below is this: *in all regimes, **concatenate + transpose** is the fastest algorithm.*

I've done some simple explorations of how the solution scales with both *k* and *N*, looking scalings in both the *k ~ N* regime, and also the *k << N* regime. It's worth noting, though, that even for very large *N*, the runtimes are less than 1s, so only for MCMC-type applications should one every really fuss over this sort of thing.

Here's the summary of the tests I have run:

- First, I can quantitatively confirm the speed tests run by David Z. Moreover, in the regime he explored, I find that the differences he finds are robust, and not simple fluctuations. See below.
- In the *k << N* regime, I notice no appreciable difference between **vstack** and **concatenate + transpose**. In this regime, the timings they return are within 1-5% regardless of the values of *k* and *N*.
- In the *k << N* regime, I notice no appreciable difference between **column_stack** and **pre-allocate & slice-wise assignment**. In this regime, the timings they return are within 1-5% regardless of the values of *k* and *N*.
- In the *k << N* regime, **vstack** is 50-500% faster than **column_stack**. This fractional speed difference only slowly increases with *N*, but rapidly increases with *k*. The larger *N*, the more rapidly the rate of fractional increase with *k*.
- In the *k ~ N* regime (not relevant for my problem, but possibly in others), **concatenate + transpose** is the fastest, with **pre-allocate & slice-wise assignment** trailing by 10-50%.
- In the *k ~ N* regime, **column_stack** and **vstack** are roughly the same speed, which is 500-1000% times slower than **concatenate + transpose**.

So, as I said above, the upshot is that **concatenate + transpose** is the fastest in all regimes:

```
p = np.concatenate((x, y, z)).reshape((3, len(x))).T
```

However, in the regime that is relevant to the original question, the **vstack** method has equivalent performance and a little less rigamarole to the syntax:

```
p = numpy.vstack((x, y, z)).T
```

Comment: What about `np.array([x,y,z]).T`?  In my small timings it is on the par with the `np.concatenate([x,y,z]).reshape(3,-1).T`